# resizable, fixed position element; responsive, relatively positioned content

Tags: css, css-position, resizable

I have a fixed div `#summary` which changes height. It needs to always show at the top of the window. Below it I have content `#catalogueContainer` which i need to re-position when the fixed div above changes height. I need to be able to scroll through using the window scroll bar.

I understand the only way to keep the `#summary` div at the top of the window is to give it a fixed position. When doing this, `#catalogueContainer` has no relationship to it and so i can't re-position using CSS when `#summary` changes height. The only way i can think is to have some javascript which listens for the re-size of summary and specifies the top position of the `#catalogue`.

1. Does this sound the most efficient solution? Code and notes below.
2. In Chrome, when i scroll through the window, the background image of #summary is left behind, but all the other content stays fixed to the top of my browser window as i scroll.

Any suggestions on fixing this?

```
#summary {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:275px;
}
```

`#summary` has re-sizable elements within, and changes height. This needs to always show at the top of the window.

```
#right {
    position:relative;
    left:275px;
    top:300px;
}
```

`#right` is the container element for all the below.

There are numerous catalogs in the `#catalogueContainer`, all in the same place, but only one is visible at a time.

```
#catalogueOne {
    position:relative;
}
```

`#catalogueOne` needs to be `relative` because there are `position:absolute` elements inside

Comment: just for my clarification, do you want something similar to the navigation bar on the [LESS site?](http://lesscss.org/)

Comment: Yes. Like that; ive got it working like the LESS navigation bar. The problem is, before scrolling, if i resize the summary div (equivalent of the navigation bar) it covers up the initial content below and there is no way of scrolling up to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could place summary and catalogue in a container (which you then place at the top). Then they just need to have a 100% width and float:left. When summary changes height, catalogue will be pushed up or down.

You could also use jQuery and use a function that places catalogue according to the height of summary. Both needs to have a fixed position.

Comment: summary is now in a container; it has fixed positioning so both left and right have 0px values for the 100% width. Not sure how float:left helps. Sorry if my questuon wasnt very clear, added some more colour in the comment above,

Comment: Float will not make any difference if they have 100% width. What I meant is I would place summary and catalogue in the same container. Do you a link?